# dataTables add Font Awesome icon instead of column name

Tags: datatables, font-awesome

I'm new in DataTables and I have a simple datatable for which I'm trying to add a Font Awesome `fa-info-circle` image instead of one column header by using `render` like:

```js
table = $("#datatable-buttons").DataTable({
            data: document.pvm.tableContent(),
            columns: [
            { data: "Info", render: function (data, type, full, meta) { if (type === 'display') return '<span style="font-size:75%" class="fa fa-info-circle"></span>' } },
            { data: "WiFi", title: "WiFi" },
            { data: "GPS", title: "GPS" },
            ],
            fixedHeader: true,
            dom: "lfBrtip",
            buttons: [
              {
                  extend: "copy",
                  className: "btn-sm"
              },
              {
                  extend: "csv",
                  className: "btn-sm",
                  filename: "DeviceMnag"
              },
              {
                  extend: "excel",
                  className: "btn-sm",
                  filename: "DeviceMnag"
              },
              {
                  extend: "pdfHtml5",
                  className: "btn-sm",
                  filename: "DeviceMnag"
              },
              {
                  extend: "print",
                  className: "btn-sm"
              },
            ],
        });
```

But it seems that my icon instead of being just in the header for `Info` column, there is no icon in the header but in the data columns instead of the correct data. Is is possible to add a icon just for one field in the header?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe when you are saying "column header" you mean the title? `render()` is for rendering column data, you set the column header through the `title` property :

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   columnDefs: [{ 
     targets: 0,
     data: '0',  //just use DOM
     title: '<i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg"></i>'
  }]     
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/6kp3tvpb/**

`title` can be a function as well :

```js
title: function() {
  return '<i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg"></i>'
}
```

But notice that this callback only is called *once*.